# C++ basic dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic

In this example I don't understand why the first element of the list cannot be dynamically allocated.
I understand the solution is BAD because I will be losing the pointer to "a" and it will be dangling. What I don't understand is why in that case my function returns an empty list.

I have simplified the example as requested:

```
ListNode* createList() {
    //Why not - ListNode* a = new ListNode(0); ?
    ListNode list(0); ListNode * a = &list;
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        a->next = new ListNode(0);
        a = a->next;
    }
    //return a->next;
    return list.next;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem? What do you mean by "empty list"? Have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what happens? Also please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Can you please provide a compilable code so we can understand the problem better and run it on our machines?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the code you show, *as you show it* (with the comments in place). There's no dangling pointers or leaks. It should return a list of five nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code such that the first element is dynamically allocated.

The problem with your suggested solution was that it would return the pointer to the end of the list (and hence the empty list) as **a** had reached the end of the list.

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
if (l1 == NULL && l2 == NULL) return NULL;
int carry = 0, sum = 0;
ListNode* a = new ListNode(0);
ListNode* head = a;
while(l1 || l2 || carry){
    sum = carry;
    if (l1 != NULL) sum+=l1->val;
    if (l2 != NULL) sum+=l2->val;     
    carry = sum/10;
    a->next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    a = a->next;
    l1 = (l1 == NULL) ? NULL : l1->next;
    l2 = (l2 == NULL) ? NULL : l2->next;
}
return head->next;
```

}

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you plan on dealing with the leak of `ListNode* a = new ListNode(0);`?

Comment: I agree that there's a leak and it is bad, but I just wanted to get the solution running with dynamic allocation

Answer (score 1):

Returning `a->next` fails you is because

```
a = a->next;
```

iterates through the list as you create it, so `a` is always pointing at the last node in the list. When you finish building the list and

```
return a->next;
```

`a` is still the last node in the list and `next` is presumably `NULL` or `nullptr`. If it isn't, yousa got a big bombast bug. There is no list returned because there is no more list to return and by this point you have lost the beginning of the list. Ooops.

On the other hand,

```
return list.next;
```

returns the node after the dummy placeholder node you created, and this the list you constructed on the dummy node. Since `list` is an local variable, it has Automatic Storage Duration and is cleaned up for you when it goes out of scope. The chain of `ListNode`s it points at were all dynamically allocated and may be returned safely.

Addendum:

In the code you removed, dynamically allocating `a` with

```
ListNode* a = new ListNode(0);
```

means at the end of the function you have `a` hanging around requiring cleanup as you noted, though this isn't called a dangling pointer, it's called a leak.

You could salvage it with

```
ListNode* a = new ListNode(0);
ListNode* start = a;
```

and later

```
return start->next;
```

but the automatic version you created with `list` requires no clean-up and is the better option because less can go wrong.

Better still would be not having a dummy node at all, and just keeping a pointer to the first created node, but that's a story for another time.